# How to find and fix the near "(": syntax error in my code

Tags: python, sqlite

**Here the user id is passed from the user's message**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['create'])
def create_the_base(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Создание базы....')
    base_create_text = message.chat.id 
    base_create_final = base_create(user_id = base_create_text)
    base_create_final.base_create_process()
```

**Below is the class that is used**

```
class base_create:
def __init__(self,user_id):
    """Обозначение переменной user_id для дальнейшего использования"""
    self.user_id = user_id
def base_create_process(self):
    """Создание базы с именем user_id"""
    base_name_by_id=str(self.user_id)
    db_connect=sqlite3.connect(base_name_by_id)
    cursor=db_connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE (base_name_by_id) ("Name" TEXT, "Day"    TEXT, "Month" TEXT, "Year" TEXT) """)
    db_connect.commit()
```

This code should create a database with the name of the user ID, so that each user can then access their database using their own ID.
At startup create_the_base(message) returns an error   **[near "(": syntax error]**   *what is the error?*
It seems to me that the error is clearly not in create_the_base, but in the class when creating the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least have gotten a stack trace pointing to the offending line of code.

I think the problem is that the table name in `CREATE TABLE` should not be parenthesized:

```
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE base_name_by_id ("Name" TEXT, "Day"    TEXT, "Month" TEXT, "Year" TEXT) """)
```

SQLite3, being an embedded database optimized for size, is not very good at giving readable error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need parenthesis around the schema name.

Here is the working SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE base_name_by_id ("Name" TEXT, "Day" TEXT, "Month" TEXT, "Year" TEXT)
```

If you want to dynamically generate that SQL command, consider using [fstring](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to do it:

```
create_table_command = f'CREATE TABLE {base_name_by_id} ("Name" TEXT, "Day" TEXT, "Month" TEXT, "Year" TEXT)'
cursor.execute(create_table_command)
```

Comment: I don't understand in what order it should work. I put it in this order. It turns out that I create a database using cursor. execute and set cursor via db_connect, and db_connect needs a database. I'm confused                                
create_table_command = f'CREATE TABLE {base_name_by_id} ("Name" TEXT, "Day" TEXT, "Month" TEXT, "Year" TEXT)'
        db_connect=sqlite3.connect(base_name_by_id)
        cursor=db_connect.cursor()
        cursor.execute(create_table_command)

Comment: The error appears [near "user id Here": syntax error]  https://i.imgur.com/9lUVua1.png

Comment: That is another issue - not related to the syntax you described.

Since you are using SQLite3 which is an embedded database, `sqlite3.connect` call will create a file with name of `base_name_by_id` string value in which it will then create a single table. So you will have a separate database with a single table for each user. I guess that what you are aiming to do is to have a single database but with separate tables per user, in which case you should probably, in any case, connect to e.g. `sqlite3.connect("user_db.db")`, and just dynamically create the tables in it.

Comment: And according to your latest comment - you are trying to create a table with the name of "user id Here" - which is against SQL conventions, you can't have whitespace in the table name. Try using a value which is in accordance with SQL syntax.

Comment: I'm not very good at this yet, I want to create a database for each user and they can change it with commands. A single database is still difficult for me. Later, with experience, I will most likely transfer everything to a single database.

Comment: There are no spaces in the user ID, just a set of numbers.